# Neo4J BatchInserter and Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, neo4j, neo4j-batch-inserter

Iam using Neo4J BatchInserter to build up a large database from scratch. I use multiple threads to read data from the BatchInserter and synchronize writes.

Problem: Sooner or later I run into an Exception when trying to **read** Properties

- with Assertions enabled in DirectRecordAccess.putInBatc
- with Assertions disabled I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds in PropertyRecord.next

  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.record.PropertyRecord.next(PropertyRecord.java:190)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.record.PropertyRecord.next(PropertyRecord.java:41)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.Loaders$2.ensureHeavy(Loaders.java:189)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.Loaders$2.ensureHeavy(Loaders.java:161)
  at org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.DirectRecordAccess$DirectRecordProxy.forReadingData(DirectRecordAccess.java:174)
  at org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.DirectRecordAccess$DirectRecordProxy.forReadingData(DirectRecordAccess.java:115)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.PropertyTraverser.getPropertyChain(PropertyTraverser.java:65)
  at org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.internal.BatchInserterImpl.getPropertyChain(BatchInserterImpl.java:1000)
  at org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.internal.BatchInserterImpl.getNodeProperties(BatchInserterImpl.java:900)

JavaDoc states: "Only one thread at a time may work against the batch inserter, multiple threads performing concurrent access have to employ synchronization."

Question(s):

- Is the BatchInserter Thread-Safe for read-only operations?
- If it is, should it be safe to have synchronized writes as long as none of the concurrent read-only threads requests data which is currently written?

Thank you for feedback!

Rüdiger

Answer (score 0):

sorry for bothering- I should just have tested it as I did now. So to all who are wondering: It seems you even need to serialize read access- or make sure that you do not try to make concurrent reads of the same properties.

What I tested:

- Create 100 nodes using BatchInserter with one String-Attribute each
- Write 2 Threads trying to fetch properties from nodes in an endless loop

What came out:

- When the two threads read properties from different nodes, everything is fine
- When the threads read from the same node the following exception is thrown

  Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.util.NoSuchElementException
      at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.record.PropertyRecord.next(PropertyRecord.java:187)
      at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.record.PropertyRecord.next(PropertyRecord.java:41)
      at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.PropertyTraverser.getPropertyChain(PropertyTraverser.java:66)
      at org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.internal.BatchInserterImpl.getPropertyChain(BatchInserterImpl.java:1000)
      at org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.internal.BatchInserterImpl.getNodeProperties(BatchInserterImpl.java:900)
      at org.hucompute.wikidragon.core.test.BatchInserterTest$ReadThread.run(BatchInserterTest.java:56)

Best Wishes,

Rüdiger